# How to log Node.js request

Tags: node.js

How to log Node.js request?

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    console.log(req);
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

For example, when using `console.log(req);`, I get long `req` object see below, but for logging it should much shorter like.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:1337
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent:
```

I read doc on [http.IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) but there is no method to get all main values at once. The closest was

```
console.log(req.method, req.url, req.httpVersion, req.headers);
```

with output

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
GET / 1.1 { host: '127.0.0.1:1337',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'user-agent': 'RestClient-Tool' }
```

Full `req` object

```
{ _readableState: 
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10,
  socket: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     errorEmitted: false,
     bytesRead: 798,
     _bytesDispatched: 156,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 1,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:1337' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
     _idleStart: 1413789077709,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular] } },
  connection: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     errorEmitted: false,
     bytesRead: 798,
     _bytesDispatched: 156,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 1,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:1337' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
     _idleStart: 1413789077709,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular] } },
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: 
   { host: '127.0.0.1:1337',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'access-control-request-method': 'POST',
     origin: 'null',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36',
     'access-control-request-headers': 'accept, content-type',
     accept: '*/*',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
     'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4' },
  trailers: {},
  _pendings: [],
  _pendingIndex: 0,
  url: '/',
  method: 'OPTIONS',
  statusCode: null,
  client: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     errorEmitted: false,
     bytesRead: 798,
     _bytesDispatched: 156,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 1,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:1337' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
     _idleStart: 1413789077709,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular] } },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  upgrade: false }
```

related to [Per request logging in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841410/per-request-logging-in-node-js)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Could it be shorter?

Comment: Is this question about how to format a string? There surely is no inbuilt method to get the output you want.

Comment: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(req.method, req.url, 'HTTP/' + req.httpVersion);
for (var name in req.headers)
  console.log(name + ':', req.headers[name]);
```